# Use of Include with async await

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asynchronous

I have an EF query in which I am returning an 'Item' by it's unique identifier. I'm using the scaffolded controller provided by MVC and this works ok, but now I want it to return a list of tags which belong to the item.

I thought I might be able to use 'Include' as shown below to eager fetch the tags. However this does not seem to be allowed when using async.

```
Item item = await db.Items.Include("Tags").FindAsync(id);
```

Can anybody explain why this won't work and suggest an alternative way to bring back the item's tags?

Cheers

Ben

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819165.aspx

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`Find()` and `FindAsync()` are methods on type `DbSet` (which is what `db.Items` is). `Include()` returns a `DbQuery` object, which is why `FindAsync()` is not available. Use `SingleOrDefaultAsync()` to do the same thing as `FindAsync()` (the difference is it will go straight to the database and won't look in the context to see if the entity exists first)...

```
Item item = await db.Items.Include("Tags").SingleOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == id);
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Clear and concise answer. Great!

Comment: Note performance diff between Single() vs First() where former looks finds record and then keeps looking to check if another exists while latter returns upon hitting the record

Answer (score 14):

Followed by @Anthony and @Korayem answer, I recommend to do as below for safer code.

```
Item item = await db.Items.Include(o => o.Tags).FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == id);

if(item == default(Item))
    return NotFound();
```