# FindAsync and Include LINQ statements

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

The code I have got so far works fine

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(Guid? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    ItemDetailModel model = new ItemDetailModel();
    model.Item = await db.Items.FindAsync(id);
    if (model.Item == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

But I want to include 1 table more and cannot use `FindAsync`

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(Guid? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    ItemDetailModel model = new ItemDetailModel();
    model.Item = await db.Items.Include(i=>i.ItemVerifications).FindAsync(id);

    if (model.Item == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }           

    return View(model);
}
```

So I am facing this error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS1061  'IQueryable' does not contain a definition for
> 'FindAsync' and no extension method 'FindAsync' accepting a first
> argument of type 'IQueryable' could be found (are you missing a
> using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any clue how to fix it?

Comment: [This post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/270ba03d-e89e-4db5-8e45-6d7f900d9442/dbsetentity-becomes-objectquery-type-in-linq-to-entities-query?forum=adonetefx) may give you some answers.  It looks like `.Include` returns an `ObjectQuery<T>` instead of a `DbSet` (which has the `FindAsync` method).

Comment: Check out this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21817569/use-of-include-with-async-await)

Answer (score 145, accepted):

The simplest is to use `FirstOrDefaultAsync` or `SingleOrDefaultAsync` instead:

```
model.Item = await db.Items.Include(i => i.ItemVerifications)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == id.Value);
```

The reason you are getting the error is because `Find` / `FindAsync` methods are defined for `DbSet<T>`, but the result of `Include` is `IQueryable<T>`.

Another way is to combine `FindAsync` with [explicit loading](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/explicit-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx):

```
model.Item = await db.Items.FindAsync(id);
if (model.Item == null)
{
    return HttpNotFound();
}
await db.Entry(model.Item).Collection(i => i.ItemVerifications).LoadAsync();
```

Comment: You could improve this answer by explaining why what he tried didn't work (see my comment under the question).

Comment: used the second option. chears

Comment: var entity = await context.Entities
    .Include("field")
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == id);

Comment: Considering the [debate over which is faster, Find vs FirstOrDefault](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14032709/1219280), which seems to point `Find` is faster, doing so negatively impacts performance.

Comment: @Veverke The question here is **not** which one is faster, but which one supports loading related data. `Find` doesn't, so any further discussion is useless. Performance concerns are ok, but functionality is first.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using a generic repository and you don't know the PK at runtime, this approach can help:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    Task<TEntity> Get(int id, string[] paths = null);
}

public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _dbSet = _context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public async Task<TEntity> Get(int id, string[] paths = null)
    {
        var model = await _dbSet.FindAsync(id);
        foreach (var path in paths)
        {
            _context.Entry(model).Reference(path).Load();
        }
        return model;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would expect this to make 2 trips to the database instead of the one when you use Include on the DbSet. It is a shame that FindAsync didn't offer the ability to include additional fields directly.

Answer (score 2):

When you program using solid principles and domain design then use generics.  The Repository pattern uses a generic class.  I pass a lambda express to the GetObjectsQueryable function.  I have setup lazy loading to be on, using code first handle bars.  However, I am moving away from lazy loading and implement a microservice architecture.  The include table is a string and you can use the nameof(xxclass) function to ensure the correct name.  The function returns and IQueryable results.  The repository class methods can be used by its derived class enhance the method is protected.  This is a dotnet.core demonstration.

```
public class Repository
    where T : class
{
    public IQueryable<T> GetObjectsQueryable(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, string includeTable="")
    {
        IQueryable<T> result = _dbContext.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
        if (includeTable != "")
            result = result.Include(includeTable);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your  OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) method of entity framework add the lazy loading proxy with the following call optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseSqlServer(connectionString);