# Entity Framework Core null object one-to-one

Tags: c#, model, null, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

Entity Framework Core null object. I have a one-to-one entity relationship.

```
public class Player
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? RatingId { get; set; }

    public Rating Rating { get; set; }
}

public class Rating
{
    public double Mean { get; set; }
}
```

In my player controller I return

```
var player = await _context.Player.FindAsync(id);
```

However this is my json

```
{
    "id": 3010,
    "ratingId": 2009,
    "rating": null,
    "displayName": "Conor",
    "partialPlayPercentage": 0.5,
    "partialUpdatePercentage": 1
}
```

Is rating supposed to be null here?

FTI When I call

```
var rating = await _context.Rating.FindAsync(2009);
```

I get the correct rating

Answer (score 3):

> Is rating supposed to be null here?

Yes, except you have [Lazy loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading) enabled, which in EF Core is not by default.

I would suggest you reading the whole [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) EF Core documentation topic which explains the 3 supported patterns - Eager, Explicit and Lazy loading. Note that there is no *implicit* loading, so you have to use one of those in order to get your navigation property loaded.

For instance, the explicit loading:

```
var player = await _context.Player.FindAsync(id);
if (player != null)
    _context.Entry(player).Reference(e => e.Rating).Load();
```

The eager loading with `Include` / `ThenInclude` is more natural choice, but it [can't be used with `Find` / `FindAsync`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40360512/findasync-and-include-linq-statements/40360633#40360633), so you need to use `FirstOrDefault` / `SingleOrDefault` (or their `Async` counterparts) like this:

```
var player = await _context.Player
    .Include(e => e.Rating)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == id);
```